# Unable to open shared file from browser(web application)

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf, hyperlink

I am using following code in my html file(test.html) to **open shared file**(pdf file) in **browser**.

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <a href="file://///90.0.0.15/Shared/test.pdf">Click Here</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

If i open html file in local system, it work perfectly.

But when i use same code in my **jsp page**(client-server application),code does not work.

Comment: You would have to serve the file using server URL, not directly from the filesystem.

Comment: i have already try using server url but unable to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a directory called "Shared" in your web path with the test.pdf in then

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <a href="Shared/test.pdf">Click Here</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @Butani Vijay what result do you get? is your server case sensitive (eg tomcat)?

Comment: We need more info, eg are you using eclipse? Have you republished changes? have you eyeballed the file in the directory on the server? Can you access any other files in sub directories? What error message do you get?

Comment: i want to open shared file using hyperlink in my web application...due to security reason i am unable to open it.....it run perfectly when i use same code in my local html file